# could'nt open aux files

Tags: bibtex

I am preparing my thesis using latex with Texmaker editor.
I compile:

1. `pdf latex` (`these_simple.tex`)
2. `bibtex` (`these_simple.aux`)

before continue compiling I receive in this stage error message

> Process started
>
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: build\these_simple.aux The style file: unsrt.bst I couldn't open auxiliary file intro.aux ---line 28 of file build\these_simple.aux : \@input{intro.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file chap1.aux ---line 29 of file build\these_simple.aux : \@input{chap1.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file chap2.aux ---line 30 of file build\these_simple.aux : \@input{chap2.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file chap3.aux ---line 31 of file build\these_simple.aux : \@input{chap3.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file conclu.aux ---line 32 of file build\these_simple.aux : \@input{conclu.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I couldn't open auxiliary file annexe.aux ---line 33 of file build\these_simple.aux : \@input{annexe.aux : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 34 of file build\these_simple.aux : \bibstyle : {plain} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no \citation commands---while reading file build\these_simple.aux Database file #1: allbiblio.bib (There were 8 error messages)
>
> Process exited with error(s)

any one can help me please?

thanks a lot.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) Are you sure you are compiling like you mention at the beginning? that `build/` part looks odd.

Comment: Don't use a build directory if you don't know how to handle it. It is **much** easier if all files are in the same folder.

Comment: it would be **so** much better if tex did not have an `--output-directory` option

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not sure about that. In one of the german group some one tried to fake this option by using a script that copied and deleted various files after the compilation and then asked lot of complicated questions why it didn't work as expected -- people always find a way to make their life more difficult than necessary.

Comment: @daleif of course i compile like  that: 1) these_simple.tex and then these_simple.aux in bibtex !

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer how can i change ?

Comment: @user117159 then please explain where the `build` information comes into the `blg` file? It doesn't not look like that when I run bibtex manually

Comment: i don't have blg file.