# BibTeX: I couldn't open auxiliary

Tags: bibtex, overleaf

So I was facing this error

```tex
BibTeX: I couldn't open auxiliary file part1/part1.aux : \@input{part1/part1.aux : }
```

and many other similar ones in this project. [BibTeX I couldn't open auxiliary file](https://www.overleaf.com/read/cghgvkvwxhyz)

Comment: @imnothere  You could probably use it at work in Overleaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a bunch of lines

```tex
\includeonly{%
  chapter1/chapter1,
  chapter2/chapter2,
  chapter3/chapter3,
  conclusion/conclusion,
  dec,abs,ack
}
```

near line 14 of mainrep.tex and these lines near line 182

```tex
\include{part1/part1}
\include{chapter1/chapter1}
\include{chapter2/chapter2}
\include{chapter3/chapter3}
\include{chapter4/chapter4}
\include{part2/part2}
\include{chapter5/chapter5}
\include{chapter6/chapter6}
\include{chapter7/chapter7}
\include{chapter8/chapter8}
\include{chapter9/chapter9}
\include{chapter10/chapter10}
\include{chapter11/chapter11}
\include{chapter12/chapter12}
\include{chapter13/chapter13}
\include{conclusion/conclusion}
```

Now I think you can see the solution. Anyway the error

```tex
BibTeX: I couldn't open auxiliary file part1/part1.aux : \@input{part1/part1.aux : }
```

is generally because `BibTeX` can't find your `*.aux` file. Another example is [couldn't open aux files [closed]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346363/129388). There too  `BibTeX` can't find the `*.aux` file.
Here the solution is to change the the code near line 14 to

```tex
\includeonly{%
  chapter1/chapter1,
  chapter2/chapter2,
  chapter3/chapter3,
  chapter4/chapter4,
  chapter5/chapter5,
  chapter6/chapter6,
  chapter7/chapter7,
  chapter8/chapter8,
  chapter9/chapter9,
  chapter10/chapter10,
  chapter11/chapter11,
  chapter12/chapter12,
  chapter13/chapter13,
  conclusion/conclusion,
  dec,abs,ack
}
```

so that poor `BibTeX`  can finally find them.

when you are doing so, don't forget the ',' (comma) anywhere and write like this

```tex
\includeonly{%
  chapter1/chapter1,
  chapter2/chapter2,
  chapter3/chapter3,
  chapter4/chapter4,
  chapter5/chapter5,
  chapter6/chapter6,
  chapter7/chapter7,
  chapter8/chapter8,
  chapter9/chapter9,
  chapter10/chapter10,
  chapter11/chapter11
  chapter12/chapter12,
  chapter13/chapter13,
  conclusion/conclusion,
  dec,abs,ack
}
```

Spot the missing ','. Got it, now fix that and don't irritate `BibTeX`  with your incompetence like me.

She just can't tolerate fools.